# Explanation for this openssl command

Tags: openssl

Any explanation for this command?

```
openssl s_client -connect $site:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -enddate | cut -d'=' -f2`
```

and What is the difference between Openssl x509 and openssl s_Client?

Answer (score 0):

[openssl s_client](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/s_client.html) is a command-line tool which makes a network connection, and performs the SSL/TLS handshake.  Various data about that handshake, including the X509 certificate of the remote server, can be printed out using `openssl s_client`.

[openssl x509](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/x509.html) is a command-line tool which knows about X509 certificates, and can decode and print out human-readable versions of the certificate data.

Let's look at your command, piece by piece.  First, we have:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect $site:443 2>/dev/null
```

says to connect to `$site` and perform an SSL/TLS handshake (and ignore any errors).  The server's X509 certificate will be displayed, along with other bits of data; you can see this yourself using *e.g.*:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=www.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=www.google.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
---
...
```

The certificate data is the base64-encoded data appearing between the "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" lines.

The next part of the command reads the output from `openssl s_client`, and prints the human-readable version of that certificate:

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -enddate
```

Specifically, the use of the `-enddate` option tells `openssl x509` to display *just* the date when the certificate expires.  So putting these together:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -enddate
notAfter=Apr 19 00:00:00 2016 GMT
```

you can see when the certificate for `www.google.com` expires.

This just leaves the last part of your command:

```
$ cut -d'=' -f2 ...
```

Notice how the end date is displayed as "notAfter=..."?  If your script/code wanted *just* the data, without that leading "notAfter=" bit, then you would need to strip it off somehow.  And that is what the `cut` command is doing here.  It splits that line on the "=" sign, and says to take the second field (`-f2`), which leaves just "Apr 19 00:00:00 2016 GMT".

This command, then:

```
openssl s_client -connect $site:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -enddate | cut -d'=' -f2
```

displays *just* the date when the certificate for `$site` expires.

Hope this helps!